# First Data service similar to Paypal IPN?

Tags: firstdata

How do I know when my First Data periodical billings run, were they approved, etc.?

I can't find any notification service, so I am wondering if there's a thing similar to PayPal Instant Payment Notification. Am I missing something?

Thanks.